# How to setup an extetended monitor with Xrandr on my Acer Aspire One?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr

I'm trying to setup an external monitor to extend my desktop for my Acer Aspire One Netbook running Ubuntu 10.10.  It is running an Atom N2600 with an Intel Integrated Graphics Controller.

lspci | grep VGA output is:

```
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 0be1 (rev 09)
```

xrandr output is:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 600, current 1024 x 600, maximum 1024 x 600
default connected 1024x600+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x600        0.0*
```

My external monitor only appears to get a signal when it is connected and I reboot the Netbook, at that time I get a mirrored display.

The resolutions of Netbook's display and external LCD are 1024x600 and 1920x1280 respectively. Xrandr never shows 2 displays.

How can i get Xrandr to see two different displays so that I can configure them?

Comment: There are some kernel modules related to the Intel GMA3600 which are not enabled by default, I'm not 100% sure what version they appeared in but I was able to find them in 3.3.4.  I had to download the source from Kernel.org and compile, then build the .deb packages. This didn't help me get an external monitor setup, and compiz still wouldn't start, but it may be a start for someone else with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default` is not a good sign and is giving me "dejavu" with [Set resolution to 1024x600 in eee pc x101CH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123953/) question.

I've seen several problems like this myself and I've asked [Xorg directly for help](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2012-April/054473.html), to no reply. I think your best bet is to file a bug, using this guide: http://intellinuxgraphics.org/how_to_report_bug.html